# How to select multiple value in same columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here are table structure and example data

table datalinkinterface

```
nodeid | ifindex | nodeparentid | parentifindex
100000 | 3 | 100004 | 11
100001 | 3 | 100007 | 100
100002 | 5 | 100009 | 66
```

table node

```
nodeid | nodesysname
100000 | ant
100001 |bird
100002 | cat
100004 | dog
100007 | egg
100009 | fish
```

table snmpinterface

```
nodeid |  snmpifiname | snmpphysaddr | snmpifdescr | snmpifindex
100000 | 1/1/1 | 00:AA | AAA | 3
100001 | 1/1/2 | 00:BB | BBB | 3
100002 | 1/1/3 | 00:CC | CCC | 5
100004 | 2/1/1 | 00:DD | DDD | 11
100007 | 2/1/2 | 00:EE | EEE | 100
100009 | 2/1/3 | 00:FF | FFF | 66
```

table ipinterface

```
nodeid | ipaddr
100000 | 192.168.0.1 |3
100001 | 192.168.0.2 | 3
100002 | 192.168.0.3 |5
100004 | 192.168.0.4 |11
100007 | 192.168.0.5 |100
100009 | 192.168.0.6 |66
```

What I would like to get is

```
nodeid | ifindex | nodeparentid | parentifindex     
to 

|srcnodesysname |srcsnmpifname | srcsnmpphyaddr | srcipaddr| srcsnmpifdescr |destnodesysname |destsnmpifname | destsnmpphyaddr | destipaddr| destsnmpifdescr |

(Ex.)
100000 | 3 | 100004 | 11    
to
ant | 1/1/1 | 00:AA | 192.168.0.1 | AAA | dog | 2/1/1 | 00:DD | 192.168.0.4 | DDD
```

How can I write sql statement to query to get result like this.

Comment: Postgresql. I want to get detailed info of records in table datalinkinterface.

Comment: You still didn't show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant you want to return results from the node and include the parent node on the same query?  If so, just use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT n.nodesysname, s.snmpifiname, s.snmpphysaddr, i.ipaddr, s.snmpifdescr ,
   n2.nodesysname parentnodesysname, s2.snmpifiname parentsnmpifiname, s2.snmpphysaddr parentsnmpphysaddr, i2.ipaddr parentpaddr, s2.snmpifdescr parentsnmpifdescr
FROM Node n
  JOIN datalinkinterface d ON n.nodeid = d.nodeid
  JOIN snmpinterface s ON n.nodeid = s.nodeid
  JOIN ipinterface i ON n.nodeid = i.nodeid
  LEFT JOIN node n2 ON d.nodeparentid = n2.nodeid
  LEFT JOIN snmpinterface s ON n2.nodeid = s2.nodeid
  LEFT JOIN ipinterface i ON n2.nodeid = i2.nodeid
```

I've used `LEFT JOIN` to get the parent results in case no parent exists.

Good luck.

Comment: Your query makes my postgresql db stucked. However,Thank you for your help.